# how to implement a interface method in Java

Tags: java, interface

When the below code is compiled the compiler shows an error:

> InterfaceTest.java:19: error: cannot find symbol      knightObj.dispBK();

```
public class InterfaceTest{
    public static interface Knight{
        public void embark();
    }
    public static class BraveKnight implements Knight{
        private int id;
        public BraveKnight(int id){
            this.id = id;
        }
        public void dispBK(){
            System.out.println("ID: "+id);
        }
        public void embark(){
            System.out.println("ID: "+id);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Knight knightObj = new BraveKnight(101);
        knightObj.dispBK();
    }
}
```

What may be the possible cause?

Comment: No you can't access that method, you ll have to at least declare method in Interface.

Comment: Or use this `BraveKnight k = new BraveKnight(101);` if compilation error is the only concern.

Comment: ZeroOne is right. To see the method initiate the object this way BraveKnight knightObj = new BraveKnight(101);

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/206623/why-does-java-compiler-decide-whether-you-can-call-a-method-based-on-the-refere

Comment: @TheNewIdiot @ Stefan Beike this is bad advice to a noob - coding against some implemantion thwarts the idea of separating an interface from its implementation!

Comment: @GyroGearless Hence I mentioned *if compilation error is the only concern.* !

Comment: @Vishnu If any of the current answers satisfy you, could you please mark one of them as accepted? I noticed you also have five other questions without accepted answers, you should close those too or specify what's missing from their answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [stated in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html):

> When you define a new interface, you are defining a new reference data
>   type. You can use interface names anywhere you can use any other data
>   type name. If you define a reference variable whose type is an
>   interface, any object you assign to it must be an instance of a class
>   that implements the interface.

`dispBK()` is method of class.
& `Knight` is interface and method is not declared in interface so you can't.

add :

`public void dispBK();` in your interface and then it will work.

An Interface reference can hold Object of IMPL if only that all methods declared in interface.

OR you ll have to access that method using Impl object.

Answer (score 6):

`Knight` is your interface, it does not define a method called `dispBK()`. Your `knightObj` object is of type `Knight`, so you need to cast it to `BraveKnight` to be able to call the `dispBK()` method.

Alternatively you could add the `dispBK()` method into your interface.

Your third option is to initialize your object like this: `BraveKnight knightObj = new BraveKnight(101);`.

I warmly recommend using some IDE such as Eclipse, they will catch easy errors like this.

Answer (score 1):

Add public void dispBK() to interface and then you can implement it

Answer (score 0):

Method from child is not visible to parent. Here `knightObj` is an instance of parent interface `Knight` and you are trying to invoke a method of its child which is not visible. You should either add that `dispBK()` method to `Kinght` interface or use casting like `((BraveKnight)knightObj).dispBK();`

Answer (score 0):

An interfaace defines the minimum set of methods that the concrete class has to implement.  That way you know that if you have a range of Knight objects (such as **BraveKnight**, **CowardlyKnight** and **GoodKnight**) they must all define the **embark()** method.

If you define your KnightObj variable as the Knight interface, then the methods of Knight are the only ones that are *directly* accessible.

However, you have instantiated your KnightObj as a new BraveKinght(101), this means that you can still access the additional methods of BraveKnight, if you cast your variable using

```
(BraveKnight)KnightObj.dispBK();
```

**More detailed EXAMPLE:**

You use this when passing parameters to functions or inside arrays, collections, such as

```
ArrayList<Knight> allKnight = new ArrayList<Knight>();
allKnight.add(new BraveKnight(105));
allKnight.add(new CowardlyKnight(13));
allKnight.add(new GoodKnight(88));
```

To test which concrete class you actually have, you use **instanceof** to evaluate it, ie

```
for (Knight eachKnight : allKnight) {
    // No need to cast this, as all Knightly objects must implement it.
    eachKnight.embark();

    if (eachKnight instanceof BraveKnight) {
         (BraveKnight)eachKnight.dispBK();
    } else if (eachKnight instanceof CowardlyKnight) {
         (CowardlyKnight)eachKnight.runaway();
    } // no test for GoodKnight - he's always good
}
```